# How can one provide colour to tab completion in tcsh?

Tags: colors, autocomplete, tcsh

([Crossposted from StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13766313/923794))

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063225/how-to-color-a-prompt-on-freebsd-cshrc) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12063749/923794) teach us how to introduce colour into tcsh prompts.

[This webpage](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/174664-how-change-color-when-doing-echo-tcsh.html) explains nicely how to get colour into any output of the `echo` command:

```
> echo \\e[1\;30mBLACK\\e[0m
BLACK
> echo '\e[1;30mBLACK\e[0m'
BLACK
```

The word 'BLACK' in the example above is printed with a black (or darkgrey) foreground colour (depending on the overall color scheme).

Now I'd like to introduce this into the `[TAB]` command autocompletion feature of `tcsh`. I tried:

```
complete testcmd 'p/*/`echo '"'"'\e[1;30mf834fef\e[0m'"'"'`/'
```

And I get:

```
> testcmd [TAB]
> testcmd ^[\[1\;30mf834fef^[\[0m
```

Obviously the characters lose their special meaning. Hopefully I just did not get the escaping right. But I tried several other ways. So any help is appreciated.

The real use case is that I've got a command completion that offers three different types of completions and I'd like to visually distinguish the types. Also the alternatives are computed by an external command. That is why I need the completion to use the backticks with an external command, such as `echo`. I don't care about the details of this command. If you make it work in any way with the `tcsh`'s `complete` command I'll probably be able to adapt (thinking `perl -pe` wrappers and such).

The reason why I believe this *has* to work somehow is that the tcsh itself offers coloured command completion if you e.g. type `ls [TAB]`. That works correctly in my setup. Also you can use `ls -1F` inside the autocompletion and the colours that `ls` outputs are also piped through. An example would be:

```
complete testcmd 'p/*/`ls -1F`/'
```

Update: As user mavin [points out on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13892780/923794), the colourization of `ls` in this example is indeed not piped through. The colours of `ls` are lost, but the auto completion can reapply colours according to LS_COLOURS variable based on hints such as the `/` and `*` marker endings as added by the ls. This can be verified by doing

```
complete testcmd 'p/*/`ls --color -1`/'
```

which fails to provide colour, and only provides garbled output. (Literally pipes through the escape character sequences)

I'm on `tcsh` version 6.13.00

Any ideas? Pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible, the way I'd like it to work. On Stack Overflow, user mavit provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13892780/923794) which is the one closest to my sought after behaviour.

If you have a better solution without the drawbacks discussed in the various answers and comments, please add your answer here or on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

try add: `set color` in ~/.cshrc or ~/.tcshrc

Comment: This is already set. As such this is not an answer to the question. This could have been posted as a comment to the question. As a new user you can not yet post comments. Try to post meaningful questions and/or answers first. Welcome to the StackEchange! :-)

Comment: @cfi This **is** an Answer, insofar as Stack Exchange goes: it looks to me like it attempts to answer the question. Whether it *actually* answers this particular question is up for debate (via comments and votes).  I see that you self-answered this question nearly 10 years ago (!) with "it's not possible", so I'd urge you to consider this Answer and reply with "I tried it and it didn't work in this way: A, B, C" -- or that it partially works, or perhaps that it solves the problem, at which point you could move the checkmark. Thank you!

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @user: My statement "That works correctly in my setup. Also you can use ls -1F inside the autocompletion and the colours that ls outputs are also piped through" implies that `ls` is set up already to use colouring. `set color` in the csh only causes the builtin `ls-F` to use colours, and passes `--color=auto` to `ls` (see man csh -> Variables -> color). 
This answer is not providing any new information.